# Query MongoDB with shell and Robomongo and receiving different results

Tags: mongodb-query

If I insert a value into my Mongo database. Then I query the shell and get the expected value :

```
"Value" : 8.7363636
```

If I use the same query in MongoVUE I also get the expected result.

If I use the same query in Robomongo.

I get the following output in text mode:

```
"Value" : 8.736363600000001
```

I get the following output in tree mode:

```
"Value" : 8.7363634
```

Anyone come across this issue?? Or could it be a bug?? I have posted this [here](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues) too... but no reply yet.

Comment: Seems like a decimal precision issue. The numbers are exactly the same asides from the trailing 00000001, which only happens in robomongo from your comments.

Comment: @RabidDog5150 true.. This seems like a bug in Robomongo to me. If I get to the bottom of this I will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was marked as a bug [here](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/699).

"It looks like this is a floating point value which cannot be exactly represented in decimal, so depending on the rounding may have slightly different display outcomes. It seems like Robomongo is rounding to 6 digits in tree view (I see "8.736364") and not rounding at all in text mode. If you query the value programmatically (i.e. db.foo.findOne({"Value" : 8.7363636}).Value) the JavaScript rounding matches the mongo shell (and your original input).

I would expect the outcome should be consistent with the mongo shell."

Comment: This has been fixed in release 0.9.0 RC3- http://blog.robomongo.org/robomongo-0-9-0-rc3-released/